# How to run spark 3.2.0 on google dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Currently, google dataproc does not have spark 3.2.0 as an image. The latest available is 3.1.2. I want to use the pandas on pyspark functionality that spark has released with 3.2.0.

I am doing the following steps to use spark 3.2.0

1. Created an environment 'pyspark' locally with pyspark 3.2.0 in it
2. Exported the environment yaml with `conda env export > environment.yaml`
3. Created a dataproc cluster with this environment.yaml. The cluster gets created correctly and the environment is available on master and all the workers
4. I then change environment variables. `export SPARK_HOME=/opt/conda/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark` (to point to pyspark 3.2.0),  `export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/spark/conf` (to use dataproc's config file) and, `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/conda/miniconda3/envs/pyspark/bin/python` (to make the environment packages available)

Now if I try to run the pyspark shell I get:

```
21/12/07 01:25:16 ERROR org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue: Listener AppStatusListener threw an exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt(StringLike.scala:304)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toInt$(StringLike.scala:304)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:33)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.parseHostPort(Utils.scala:1126)
        at org.apache.spark.status.ProcessSummaryWrapper.<init>(storeTypes.scala:527)
        at org.apache.spark.status.LiveMiscellaneousProcess.doUpdate(LiveEntity.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.status.LiveEntity.write(LiveEntity.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.status.AppStatusListener.update(AppStatusListener.scala:1213)
        at org.apache.spark.status.AppStatusListener.onMiscellaneousProcessAdded(AppStatusListener.scala:1427)
        at org.apache.spark.status.AppStatusListener.onOtherEvent(AppStatusListener.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus.doPostEvent$(SparkListenerBus.scala:28)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.doPostEvent(AsyncEventQueue.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus.postToAll$(ListenerBus.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.super$postToAll(AsyncEventQueue.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.$anonfun$dispatch$1(AsyncEventQueue.scala:105)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$2.$anonfun$run$1(AsyncEventQueue.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1404)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$2.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:96)
```

However, the shell does start even after this. But, it does not execute code. Throws exceptions:
I tried running:
`set(sc.parallelize(range(10),10).map(lambda x: socket.gethostname()).collect())`
but, I am getting:

```
21/12/07 01:32:15 WARN org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator: Container from a bad node: container_1638782400702_0003_01_000001 on host: monsoon-test1-w-2.us-central1-c.c.monsoon-credittech.internal. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: [2021-12-07 
01:32:13.672]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1638782400702_0003_01_000001
Exit code: 1
[2021-12-07 01:32:13.717]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
ltChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/12/07 01:31:43 ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Executor self-exiting due to : Driver monsoon-test1-m.us-central1-c.c.monsoon-credittech.internal:44367 disassociated! Shutting down.
21/12/07 01:32:13 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager: ShutdownHook '$anon$2' timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager.executeShutdown(ShutdownHookManager.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ShutdownHookManager$1.run(ShutdownHookManager.java:95)
21/12/07 01:32:13 ERROR org.apache.spark.util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread shutdown-hook-0
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1475)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.awaitTermination(Executors.java:675)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.MessageLoop.stop(MessageLoop.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.$anonfun$stop$1(Dispatcher.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.$anonfun$stop$1$adapted(Dispatcher.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.stop(Dispatcher.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.cleanup(NettyRpcEnv.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.shutdown(NettyRpcEnv.scala:309)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.stop(Executor.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.$anonfun$new$2(Executor.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$2(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1996)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.$anonfun$runAll$1(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.runAll(ShutdownHookManager.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anon$2.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and the same error repeats multiple times before coming to a stop.

What am I doing wrong and How can I use python 3.2.0 on google dataproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can achieve this by:

1. Create a dataproc cluster with an environment (`your_sample_env`) that contains pyspark 3.2 as a package
2. Modify `/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-env.sh` by adding

```
SPARK_HOME="/opt/conda/miniconda3/envs/your_sample_env/lib/python/site-packages/pyspark"
SPARK_CONF="/usr/lib/spark/conf"
```

at its end

3. Modify `/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf` by commenting out the following configurations

```
spark.yarn.jars=local:/usr/lib/spark/jars/*
```

Now, your spark jobs will use pyspark 3.2

Comment: Is there a way to do this on an existing dataproc cluster? I.e. install a new pyspark installation on top and somehow refer to it

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc Serverless for Spark was just released with Spark 3.2.0 support: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless

Answer (score 0):

@milominderbinder 's answer didn't work for me in the notebooks. I used the [pip install script](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/blob/master/python/pip-install.sh) given by  google and added the below code in main.

```html
function main() {
  install_pip
  pip install pyspark==3.2.0
  sed -i '4d;27d' /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
  cat << EOF | tee -a /etc/profile.d/custom_env.sh /etc/*bashrc >/dev/null
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/conda/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/
export SPARK_CONF=/usr/lib/spark/conf
EOF
  sed -i 's/\/usr\/lib\/spark/\/opt\/conda\/miniconda3\/lib\/python3.8\/site-packages\/pyspark\//g' /opt/conda/miniconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json

  if [[ -z "${PACKAGES}" ]]; then
    echo "WARNING: requirements empty"
    exit 0
  fi
  run_with_retry pip install --upgrade ${PACKAGES}

}
```

This makes it work in jupyterlab with Python3 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty script, done in initialization actions on Dataproc image 2.0:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

spark_version="3.3.0"

cd /opt

if [[ ! -L /opt/spark ]]; then
    archive_filename="spark-${spark_version}-bin-without-hadoop.tgz"
    rm -rf spark*
    wget "https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-${spark_version}/${archive_filename}"
    tar xvfz "${archive_filename}"
    rm -f spark*.tgz*
    ln -s spark-* spark
fi

# This will cause spark to fallback to defaults. There's probably a better way.
sed -i '/^spark\.yarn\.jars/d' /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

# By default, Dataproc uses Hive. For unknown reasons, this doesn't work, so we replace it with 'in-memory'.
sed -i '/^spark\.sql\.catalogImplementation/d' /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
echo "spark.sql.catalogImplementation=in-memory" >>/usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

# note: weird filename to ensure this runs after all the other profile.d scripts...
{
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    echo 'export PATH=/opt/spark/bin:$PATH'
    echo "export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/usr/lib/spark/conf"
    echo "export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark"
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$(ZIPS=("$SPARK_HOME"/python/lib/*.zip); IFS=:; echo "${ZIPS[*]}"):$PYTHONPATH'
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    echo 'export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)'
} >/etc/profile.d/zzzzzzzzzzzzz-custom-spark.sh
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/zzzzzzzzzzzzz-custom-spark.sh
```